# CsvHelper ClassMap constructor parameter, when using Reference<>

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have the following ClassMap:

```
internal sealed class MyOuterMap : ClassMap<MyOuterClass>
{
    public MyOuterMap()
    {
        References<MyInnerMap>(x => x.MyInnerClassProperty);
    }
}

internal sealed class MyInnerMap : ClassMap<MyInnerClass>
{
    public MyInnerMap(string p1, int p2)
    {
    }
}
```

The client code is:

```
using var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, config);
csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap(new MyInnerMap("hello", 42));
csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<MatchMap>();
```

Got error message:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Constructor 'InnerMap()' was not
> found.'

I do understand the message, and also understand that CsvHelper tries to instantiate a new instance of MyInnerMap. The question is why not CsvHelper uses the instance I registered?

Comment: Is this C++ or C# or some other language? Please [edit] to provide at least a language tag.

Comment: It looks like based on the error message possibly a typo in your code or either a typo on the error message "InnrerMap()" has an extra r in it.

Comment: @BateTech, thx it was a typo in here SO, correted

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library but it looks like it isn't shipped with .net core but is a 3rd party lib.  Have you checked the docs here: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/  or source here https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper ?  They may be able to give some insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `References<TClassMap>(Expression<Func<TClass, object>> expression, params object[] constructorArgs)` has an additional `params` where you can pass the arguments for the `MyInnerMap` constructor.

```cs
void Main()
{
    using var streamReader = new StringReader("Id,Name,InnerId,Description\n1,Record Name,12,A description\n1,Record Name,42,A description");
    using var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap(new MyOuterMap("hello!!", 42));

    var records = csvReader.GetRecords<MyOuterClass>().ToList();
    
    records.Dump();
}

internal sealed class MyOuterMap : ClassMap<MyOuterClass>
{
    public MyOuterMap(string p1, int p2)
    {
        Map(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References<MyInnerMap>(b => b.Bar, p1, p2);
    }
}

internal sealed class MyInnerMap : ClassMap<MyInnerClass>
{
    public MyInnerMap(string p1, int p2)
    {
        Map(x => x.Id).Name("InnerId");
        Map(x => x.Description).Convert(args =>
        {
            if (args.Row.GetField<int>("InnerId") == p2)
            {
                return p1;
            }
            else
            {
                return args.Row.GetField("Description");
            }
        });
    }
}

public class MyOuterClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyInnerClass Bar { get; set; }
}

public class MyInnerClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The other way to do it would be to map the inner class inside the outer map.

```cs
void Main()
{
    using var streamReader = new StringReader("Id,Name,InnerId,Description\n1,Record Name,12,A description\n1,Record Name,42,A description");
    using var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap(new MyOuterMap("hello", 42));

    csvReader.GetRecords<MyOuterClass>().ToList().Dump();
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

internal sealed class MyOuterMap : ClassMap<MyOuterClass>
{
    public MyOuterMap(string p1, int p2)
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Map(x => x.Bar.Id).Name("InnerId");
        Map(x => x.Bar.Description).Convert(args =>
        {
            if (args.Row.GetField<int>("InnerId") == p2)
            {
                return p1;
            }
            else
            {
                return args.Row.GetField("Description");
            }
        });
    }
}

public class MyOuterClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyInnerClass Bar { get; set; }
}

public class MyInnerClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you create an instance of `MyInnerMap` with specific parameters and register it with `CsvHelper`:

```
csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap(new MyInnerMap("hello", 42));
```

`CsvHelper` doesn't use this particular instance to handle its mapping operations. Instead, it creates its own instance internally when needed, typically using the parameterless constructor. `CsvHelper` doesn't directly utilize the instances you've manually instantiated for mapping operations.

Comment: a)  then what is the use case of that RegisterClassMap overload which takes an instance? b) please read the OP, the question is how to use constructor parameter with ClassMaps...

Comment: You can create a factory method or a factory class to generate the instances with the required parameters.